# specify server root as a parameter when launching nginx

Tags: nginx

I've put nginx into `/d/webservers/nginx` on Windows and added it to the PATH. Now I try to run `nginx` from different folder but get the following error:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "logs/error.log" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)

2015/03/22 10:09:25 [emerg] 5516#3056: CreateFile() "C:\Users\username/conf/nginx.conf" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

It seems that nginx can't find it's server root folder `/d/webservers/nginx` where config and logs folder exists. Is there any way to pass as an argument the pass to the server root folder? Something like it's done for Apache: `httpd -d /d/Webservers/Apache24'`

Answer (score 1):

nginx -c d:/webservers/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Comment: The error is quite simple "CreateFile() "logs/error.log" failed ", it expects this folder so create it.